# I want to reset a column of the table after a month

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have a table e.g `T1`

[image]

I want to reset all rows where status = 0 and store these data (where status=0) in another table `T2`, but I want to do this after a month.
Kindly suggest what to do.

I am doing this in FEE Management system where a student will pay fee once in a month and after a month status should be "0" because I will use this table again for the next month. and i want to copy all data where status=1 in another table before reset the status column.

Comment: please provide more information about your use case, the data you'll have, and why are you trying this. We can't help you just with this...

Comment: We would call this a historic table for what you are doing. Unless status refers to completed? Anyways, that should be handled on a procedure.

Comment: thanks to responds, i am doing this in FEE Management system where a student will pay fee once in a month and after a month status should be "0" because i will use this table again for the next month.
and i want to copy all data where status=1 in another table before reset the status column

Answer (score 1):

Try using a transaction,

```
BEGIN;
  INSERT INTO t2
    SELECT *
    FROM t1
    WHERE status=0
    FOR UPDATE;

  DELETE FROM t1
    WHERE status=0;

COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know MySQL specifically, but from the decription I'd add a table column "FeeDueDate" which is a date, and I would not delete data from the table.  For each date when a student is due to pay, I'd add a new row.

(However, due to business rules as well as privacy legislation like GDPR, you may have to eliminate data when it is no longer required.  But you also may be required to keep data.)

However, I'm assuming a situation where a student has to pay by the first day of each month - for instance.  Maybe instead you want a student to pay on any date and then receive the service until the same day next month.  Then if they don't pay on time, they simply don't get service until they do pay.  In that case, you could add a column "FeePaidDate".  And maybe "FeeDueDate" as well, being the same day 1 month later, because it's fiddly to calculate that by comparing dates on the fly.  On the other hand, that gives you a different problem if the first date is January 29th for instance.  Unless you say that a "month" is thirty days.  Or that paying on January 29th inly gets you 3 days.

Anyway, every night, - or every month - you  copy data, then update "status", to show which students' payments have expired, depending on when they paid.